# Error Building Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, dlib

I am connecting the dlib library to a project in visual studio 2015 
I don't know what to write in the linker in my case. I think it is the reason why I get many mistakes when I am trying to build solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqMpO.png)

Comment: Show your code and let us know about your environment. It seems you have included libs or dlls, but linker can't find its.

Comment: I copied code from here http://dlib.net/video_tracking_ex.cpp.html

Comment: You have build and add libs like described here: https://github.com/davisking/dlib

Comment: yes, like there